# Search the second file from the first and output to third file in python

Tags: python, search

I want to search the occurrence of lines in the second file by using the first file as input and output to the third file. Also it got to be fast The list is second file is above 200k and the first above 75k.

```
**FILE 1**
1234
2324
534
235
1
643

**FILE 2**

643, 30, , , People, email@example.com,.....
1234, 45, , , People, email@example.com,.....
643, 32, , , People, email@example.com,.....
4536, 654, , , People, email@example.com,.....
898, 354, , , People, email@example.com,.....

**FILE 3**
643, 30, , , People, email@example.com,.....
1234, 45, , , People, email@example.com,.....
```

That's it guys. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have any code you can share with us?

Comment: I don't have any code to share. I'm not that good with python

Comment: SO is not the right place to post questions like this. It is intended to be a place to ask specific questions about programming, not to have code written for you. Although Celeo has posted an answer for you, you shouldn't expect this to happen every time, and should avoid asking "questions" that are just a description of a set of requirements for a script or program you want.

Comment: It works I tried it again it works okay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the ids from the first file, and then use the lines of the second file to check if the starting number is in the list of ids you collected. Add matches to a list and write the list to the third file.

```
ids = []
with open('file1') as f:
    ids.extend(id.strip() for id in f)
matches = []
with open('file2') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.split(',')[0] in ids:
            matches.append(line)
with open('file3', 'w') as f:
    for match in matches:
        f.write(match)
```